# I want to replace a column text Test's as Test using replace command in SQL

Tags: sql, replace

I want to replace a column text Test's as Test using replace command in SQL.
I have tried using

```
UPDATE table 
    SET column = REPLACE(column, 'test's', 'test');
```

But in test's, it is taking ' as extra quotation.

Answer (score 3):

To include a single quote in a string constant, just double it:

```
UPDATE table
    SET column = REPLACE(column, 'test''s', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = REPLACE(column, 'test''s', 'test');
```

Or

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = REPLACE(column, 'test\'s', 'test');
```

Or

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = REPLACE(column, e'test\'s', 'test');
```